# Expressing a decimal percentage as a ratio

Tags: percentages, ratio

Maths newbie here. How would I express a decimal percentage such as 90.3 as a ratio ("one in...")?

I've done a search and the explanations aren't too clear at all. I'm about to enrol on to a mathematics course because I must admit that my mathematical skills are incredibly poor. Before I start on the course I'm trying to pick-up some '101s' and basic skills.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$90.3\% = \frac{90.3}{100} = \frac{903}{1000}$$

As in "$903$ of every $1000$ students love mathematics."

Comment: Thank you :) So 903 because 1 isn't an available simplification? I think I was confused by the practise question that ends with the example of "1 in...". Seems far too simple - thanks!

Comment: +1 that percent looks far from reality though :P

Comment: I agree with that 100%! :)